# Grails projections ignoring sort order with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting, grails, groovy, criteria

How do you order the results of projections in a [Grails criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) when using [MongoDB](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb)?

It seems that sorting is ignored by MongoDB.  The code below correctly returns a list of sorted book titles when run with the Grails default in-memory HSQLDB database.  Switching over to MongoDB causes the sorting to be ignored.

**BookController.groovy**

```
class BookController {

   def library = [
      [author: "Jan", title: "HTML5"],
      [author: "Lee", title: "CSS3"],
      [author: "Sue", title: "JavaScript"]
      ]

   def titles() {
      library.each { if (!Book.findByTitle(it.title)) new Book(it).save() }
      def ids = Book.createCriteria().list() {
         projections { id() }
         order "title"
         }
      def titles = ids.collect { Book.get(it).title }
      render titles as JSON
      }

}
```

Result with default DB (correct):

```
   ["CSS3","HTML5","JavaScript"]
```

Result with MongoDB (wrong):

```
   ["HTML5","CSS3","JavaScript"]
```

Note that the above book example is just some trivial code to illustrate the problem.  The real goal is to generate a list of domain IDs sorted by a field of the domain so that the domain can be iterated over in the desired order.

The actual domain I'm dealing with is too large to fit in memory.  In other words, this would crash the application: `Book.list().title.sort()`

Below is additional background information.

**Book.groovy**

```
class Book {    
   String title
   String author
   static mapWith = "mongo"
}
```

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
...
compile ":mongodb:1.3.1"
...
```

**DataSource.groovy**

```
...
grails {
   mongo {
      host = "localhost"
      port = 27017
      databaseName = "book-store"
      }
   }
```

Comment: All the examples I can find showing order have the parameter in parens and include direction, like  order("title","asc") - have you tried that?   Also, is the order correct when you don't include projections?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: Yep, I've tried with and without parens and with and without direction.  I've even tried adding `order` to the criteria.  Example: `criteria = criteria.order("order")`  The sort order is correct when done without `projections`, so it seems the issues is specific to using `projections` on MongoDB.

Comment: What is the sort order of the ids in the criteria return value `ids`? And does anything changes if you alter `projections { id() }` to ? `projections { property('id') }`

Comment: @matcauthon, Projections on the `id` field do not work with the same notation as other fields.  The `id()` notation seems to be the way to go.  See: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projections support has been rewritten to use the MongoDb aggregation framework in 3.0 of the plugin. So the example where should work in 3.0 with or without ordering. See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-305

Relevant commit https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/commit/1d1155d8a9e29a25413effce081c21a36629137d

Comment: This sounds great, but I have not yet been able to test it.  We do a few projections on List fields and that is apparently not supported in v3.0.  When we figure out a way to upgrade to v3.0, I'll post an update.

Comment: @Graeme Rocher  I'm unable to perform sort here  => table.find(query).sort({ "eventStartsAt" : -1 }).skip(offset).limit(max)